# Вы навсегда остались с нами (-) Примером светлым(,) как нам жить

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я расставил знаки препинания в следуюших двух строчках из стихотворения:
Вы навсегда остались с нами - 
Примером светлым, как нам жить

Мои соображения: Тире ставится перед приложением, стоящим в конце предложения. Запятая ставится между главным и придаточным предложениями

Comment: В конце ставится точка, если нет возражений и продолжения предложения. Тире будет выглядеть не как чёрточка, если набрать alt+151.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постановка знаков препинания не совсем корректна (в частности, приложение здесь отсутствует), поэтому предлагается такой вариант:  Вы навсегда **остались** с нами  **Примером** светлым –  как нам жить.

В этом случае "остались примером" –  составное именное сказуемое, перед придаточным предложением ставится авторское тире вместо запятой.